# jQuery to modify SharePoint 2010 Column Width

Tags: jquery, sharepoint-2010

I feel this is a remedial question, but I have been battling for several days now….so forgive me.  I am working in SharePoint 2010 and have a task list in Gantt View.  The list has 6 columns plus the gantt chart.  These tasks are sync’ed (created) with Microsoft Project 2010.  Since the column widths are not persistent in SharePoint, I would like Column 2 (Title) to have a default width of 450px  (should be simple enough…right?).  I have tried many jquery options using the CEWP to try and set this column width.  I thought this would be easier that it appears…Can someone help me determine where I am off the track?  I have hunted the internet until by browser couldn't take it anymore...any help would be greatly appreciated.

Options I have tried:  None of them seem to work…I have them in a text file in the Library (linked to the CEWP), the script is running, because I can set the splitterposition and zoom levels…just not the widths of the column.

**Option #1**

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
    $("TH.ms-vh2-nograd:contains('Title')").css("width", "450px"); 
    $("TH.ms-vb:contains('Title')").css("width", "450px"); }); 
    </script>
```

**Option #2**

```
    <script type="text/javascript"> 
    $(function() 
    { 
        $("tr.ms-viewheadertr th:contains('Title')").css("width", "450px"); 
    });
    </script>
```

**Option #3**

```
    <script type="text/javascript"> 
    ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(function()
    {
    var oldGanttControl = SP.GanttControl;
    SP.GanttControl = function()
    {
    oldGanttControl.call(this);
    var oldInit = this.Init;
    this.Init = function(jsGridControl, jsRawGridData, params)
    {
    oldInit.call(this, jsGridControl, jsRawGridData, params);
    DoCustomizations(jsGridControl);
    };
    };
    },"SPGantt.js");

    Function DoCustomizations(grid)
    {
    var columns = grid.GetColumns();
    $.each(columns, function(key, value) {
    value.width=450;});
    grid.UpdateColumns(grid.parentNode.jsgridtableviewparams.columns);
    }
    </script>
```

The Code that works is here. But can't resolve the column width.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(function()
    {
    var oldGanttControl = SP.GanttControl;
    SP.GanttControl = function()
    {
    oldGanttControl.call(this);
    var oldInit = this.Init;
    this.Init = function(jsGridControl, jsRawGridData, params)
    {
    oldInit.call(this, jsGridControl, jsRawGridData, params);
    DoCustomizations(jsGridControl);
    };
    };
    },"SPGantt.js");


    function DoCustomizations(grid) 
    {
    // Set the Splitter and Zoom Levels
    grid.SetSplitterPosition(725);
    grid.SetGanttZoomLevel(grid.GetGanttZoomLevel()+2);
    }

    </script>
```

**Results from Answer #1/Update 3**

I was determined to solve this problem yesterday, but alas....  I have tried with no results to get the function to work properly.  I have searched, read, researched, to no avail.  It appears that the syntax for the selector statement is widely varied, and so I am not sure if I have a syntax error or an issue with CEWP and it's rendering of the generating function.  Some of the variations I tried:

```
$('th[title="Title"]').css("width", "450px","important"); 
$('th[title="Title"]').css("width", "450px", "important");
$('th[title="Title"]').css('width', '450px', 'important');
$('th [title="Title"]').css("width", "450px", "important");
$("th [title='Title']").css("width", "450px", "important");
```

and on and on and on....   So I guess I have a few more questions and I will have to let it lie...

1)  Is it possible that I don't have the right JavaScript Source Library Referenced?  The scripts do not show failure or syntax issues no matter which library I reference or code I use, but don't work either.  Currently I have this one referenced....

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
```

2)  Does the SharePoint CEWP somehow interfer with the JQuery edit?  I read in another post (can't find it again); where the page was not rendered all the way before the edit was made????

**Update 4 Information**

I changed logic to what is below to try and make sure....no difference

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">  

$(function()  
{  
   $(document).ready(function() {
    //Get the th that has a title attribute and it contains the value Title 
    $('th[title="Title"]').css("width", "450px","important");  
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: I have not use sharepoint in the past however i don't see the problem with the option 1 or 2, but i do see a problem with the selector. Can you share the html of the section of that column?

Comment: Updated Post to show code that is functioning and the HTML for the JSGridControl Web Part.  I have searched for a JSGrid method to set the column widths...looks like there is a method for everything but that.  Thanks for the help

Answer (score 2):

Finally got it nailed....The finial script is below that does all the actions I was needing (for future reference of others).  Thanks so much for hanging with me and helping me out.  Combiniation of your logic and some syntax cleanup on my code and we got it resolved.  Thanks Again, I would have struggled for many more days without help!

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
JSRequest.EnsureSetup();
    //ensure document is ready
    $(document).ready(function() 
    {
        ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(function() 
        { 
            var oldGanttControl = SP.GanttControl; 
            SP.GanttControl = function() 
            { 
                oldGanttControl.call(this); 
                var oldInit = this.Init; 
                this.Init = function(jsGridControl, jsRawGridData, params) 
                { 
                    oldInit.call(this, jsGridControl, jsRawGridData, params); 
                    DoCustomizations(jsGridControl); 
                }; 
            }; 
        },"SPGantt.js"); 
    });

    function DoCustomizations(grid) 
    {
        grid.SetSplitterPosition(725); //set the splitter position
        grid.SetGanttZoomLevel(grid.GetGanttZoomLevel()+2); //set the zoom level
        $("th[title='Title']").css("width", "450px","important"); // set the column width
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Great, now there is a solution to the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the selector to: :

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
$(function() 
{ 
    //Get the th that has a title attribute
    $("th[title]").css("width", "450px","important"); 
});
</script>
```

**Update**

Does this [css reference sheet](http://www.heathersolomon.com/content/sp07cssreference.htm#WebParts) contains a reference to the element you need? Also check the selector.

Also, can you post the generated HTML instead of the generating function?

**Update two**

Ok, based on the generated code i did a example of the structure in [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/452Pp/10/) and i also added the `important` to the css atribute to asure if would work out. Although you might need to change the example to make it work for you (you have div inside the `th` so you might need to change those div's to) i'm updating the code again so you can try it this instead (changed the `T` for `t` in `title`).

**Update three**

Thank you for that, know i understand that you don't need the element to just have the attribute `title` but that it contains `Title`. There are many options to find a attribute value, however i commonly use this three:

- [Attribute Contains Prefix Selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-prefix-selector/) `[attr|="value"]`

> Description: Selects elements that have the specified attribute with a value either equal to a given string or starting with that string followed by a hyphen (-).

- [Attribute Contains Selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/) `[attr*="value"]`

> Description: Selects elements that have the specified attribute with a value containing the a given substring.

- [Attribute Equals Selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/) : `[attr="value"]`

> Description: Selects elements that have the specified attribute with a value exactly equal to a certain value.

In our specific case i suggest you to use the third option. I'm going to write a new code of block to keep a bit more of this post history.

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
$(function() 
{ 
    //Get the th that has a title attribute and it contains the value Title
    $('th[title="Title"]').css("width", "450px","important"); 
});
</script>
```

Hope it's finally fixed now.

**Update Four**

Are putting your jquery code inside jquery document ready?

**Update Five**

I've been reading that there might be a conflict using `$`, so try using `jQuery` instead.

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
   jQuery(function(){ 

      //Get the th that has a title attribute and it contains the value Title
      jQuery('th[title="Title"]').css("width", "450px","important"); 

   });
</script>
```

Comment: No go....The column width for the JSGrid appears to be set as part of the Metadata.  I don't want to post it all..it won't fit.  However, here is where the column width is set.  ,\"fieldKeys\":[\"Title\"],\"columnKey\":\"Title\",\"name\":\"Title\",\"width\":100}

Comment: I posted it in pastebin, the columnKey is almost at the bottom of the script.  http://pastebin.com/xPZN4PqX

Comment: Others have reported the same issue:  [link](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en/sharepoint2010customization/thread/13ad9b76-be65-4931-91db-adf8f4e3c4f3) and [link](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepointcustomization/thread/a9d27bb6-eb76-4ba1-a4fd-d1dd26e59825) are a couple examples.  I will keep looking as we work on it.  Thank for any help.  Bryan

Comment: thanks...I tried the modified script above...no go again.  I have posted the generated HTML (for our target area) in [pastbin](http://pastebin.com/9AYJruz0) with the column width set to 449 before I created it.  It just defaults back to 100 at origninal load.  I have not CSS reference sheets before...initial pass, I did not see a reference...will look deeper in the 2010 section.

Comment: We are getting closer, the problem is definitely with the selector.  The "th[Title]" is not getting the handle on the Title Column...however, I have verified using the IE Developers toolbar that I can change the ONE line to be 450px and it renders correctly (don't need to do the div sections).  I have put the entire generated HTML for the JSGrid Control on [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/WwVXFDnB).  Line 102 is the only place I have to capture and change...this post shows it after I changed with developers toolbar.  Thanks for hanging with me....I learning more that I thought..appreciate all

Comment: I gave her a valiaint effort, but still on the bubble.  Above, I posted the results and got two more questions for you....I think I either have a Library Issue, Syntax Problem, or the CEWP is somehow creating further issues.  Thanks

Comment: @BryanB I've been reading that there might be a conflict using the `$` , read my last update.

Comment: WE GOT IT DUDE....see final modifications below...combination of issues on my part...thanks again

Answer (score 0):

TH tags in SharePoint don't contain a title attribute.

Answer (score 0):

This probably should just be a comment on BryanB's answer, however I lack the reputation and I believe that other people will benefit from this, so here goes.

I used the solution that BryanB posted, however only changing the css width did not change the internal width that the grid stores. This caused to distinct issues:

1. The column dropdown, where you can select a sort, did not move from the original 100px default position
2. When adjusting the width of the column by dragging it would jump to the original 100px default position and then adjusted as normal.

The solution is to adjust the column width in the jsRawGridData variable before it initializes the grid. I only got it to work with the direct array reference, however the title is in there so worst case a simple loop would allow you to set a width by column title instead of position.

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
JSRequest.EnsureSetup();
    //ensure document is ready
    $(document).ready(function() 
    {
        ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(function() 
        { 
            var oldGanttControl = SP.GanttControl; 
            SP.GanttControl = function() 
            { 
                oldGanttControl.call(this); 
                var oldInit = this.Init; 
                this.Init = function(jsGridControl, jsRawGridData, params) 
                { 
                    FixColumnWidth(jsRawGridData);
                    oldInit.call(this, jsGridControl, jsRawGridData, params); 
                    DoCustomizations(jsGridControl); 
                }; 
            }; 
        },"SPGantt.js"); 
    });

    function FixColumnWidth(data)
    {
        data.Columns[1].width=450;
    }


    function DoCustomizations(grid) 
    {
        grid.SetSplitterPosition(725); //set the splitter position
        grid.SetGanttZoomLevel(grid.GetGanttZoomLevel()+2); //set the zoom level
    }
</script>
```